# What can cause a resistor to become non-ohmic?

Tags: resistors, resistance, ohms-law

Can anyone help me find some causes as to why a resistor may become non-ohmic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you make a resistor using thin wire, say steel, you will find that the resistance increases with wire temperature. So that is one example. There are special resistors designed to have a temperature dependence. Some have a negative temperature coefficient (NTC) and some have positive (PTC). They can be used for temperature sensing or other special uses (for example PTC's can act somewhat like a fuse, and NTC's can act as inrush limiters).

Comment: You need to define what you mean by non-ohmic. Has the component become open circuit and in effect looking like nearly infinite resistance? Has the component become a short circuit? Or is it still acting somewhat like a resistor but not in a linear relationship between current through and voltage drop across?

Comment: now that i think about it, this looks like a school question .... is it a school work?

Answer (score 1):

An ideal resistor follows Ohm's law by definition.
Materials which do not follow Ohm's law are not called resistors. That being said, it is possible that a material that follows the law under standard conditions fails to do so under a wide range of conditions.
Two reasons that come to mind are,

- [The Skin Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect): Which is applicable to High frequency AC circuits
- [Thermal Dependence](https://www.miniphysics.com/temperature-dependence-of-resistivity.html) of resistivity, because of which the nature of the conductor changes with temprature.

Comment: Be careful that you are not doing homework for the OP (original poster). If we suspect that it is a homework we usually prompt the OP with some clues to let him/her think it through themselves. They're supposed to be studying the subject so they should already have enough background information.